# ¿Cómo crear un modelo de tabla para poder personalizar los componentes en un JTABLE?

Tags: java, java-swing, jdbc, jtable

Tengo una clase empresa con los siguientes atributos.

```
package Logico;

public class EmpresaBeans {

    private String NUMDOCUEMPRE;
    private String RAZONEMPREV;
    private String CODTIPOACTI;
    private String NUMIPSS;
    private String RNCEMPRE;
    private String FONOEMPRE;
    private String DIREEMPRE;
    private Boolean ACTIVEMPRE;

    // 
    public EmpresaBeans() {
    }

    // 

    public String getNUMDOCUEMPRE() {
        return NUMDOCUEMPRE;
    }

    public void setNUMDOCUEMPRE(String NUMDOCUEMPRE) {
        this.NUMDOCUEMPRE = NUMDOCUEMPRE;
    }

    public String getRAZONEMPREV() {
        return RAZONEMPREV;
    }

    public void setRAZONEMPREV(String RAZONEMPREV) {
        this.RAZONEMPREV = RAZONEMPREV;
    }

    public String getCODTIPOACTI() {
        return CODTIPOACTI;
    }

    public void setCODTIPOACTI(String CODTIPOACTI) {
        this.CODTIPOACTI = CODTIPOACTI;
    }

    public String getNUMIPSS() {
        return NUMIPSS;
    }

    public void setNUMIPSS(String NUMIPSS) {
        this.NUMIPSS = NUMIPSS;
    }

    public String getRNCEMPRE() {
        return RNCEMPRE;
    }

    public void setRNCEMPRE(String RNCEMPRE) {
        this.RNCEMPRE = RNCEMPRE;
    }

    public String getFONOEMPRE() {
        return FONOEMPRE;
    }

    public void setFONOEMPRE(String FONOEMPRE) {
        this.FONOEMPRE = FONOEMPRE;
    }

    public String getDIREEMPRE() {
        return DIREEMPRE;
    }

    public void setDIREEMPRE(String DIREEMPRE) {
        this.DIREEMPRE = DIREEMPRE;
    }

    public Boolean getACTIVEMPRE() {
        return ACTIVEMPRE;
    }

    public void setACTIVEMPRE(Boolean ACTIVEMPRE) {
        this.ACTIVEMPRE = ACTIVEMPRE;
    }
```

Luego tengo una clase controladora que tiene un método que lista los registros de la base de datos.

```
package Controlador;

import Conexion.MsqlServerConnect;
import Logico.EmpresaBeans;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ControlEmpresa {

    // objetos de conexion
    ResultSet rs = null;
    CallableStatement cs = null;

    // instanciamos la cadena de conexion
    MsqlServerConnect con = new MsqlServerConnect();

    // constructor
    public ControlEmpresa() {
    }

    public List listarEmpresa(){
        List empresa = new ArrayList();
        EmpresaBeans emp;
        try {
            cs = con.conectar().prepareCall("{call PA_EMPRESA(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");;
            cs.setNull(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            cs.setNull(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            cs.setNull(3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            cs.setNull(4, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            cs.setNull(5, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            cs.setNull(6, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            cs.setNull(7, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            cs.setNull(8, java.sql.Types.BOOLEAN);
            cs.setString(9, "VERTODOS");
            rs = cs.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                emp = new EmpresaBeans();
                emp.setNUMDOCUEMPRE(rs.getString("NUMDOCUEMPRE"));
                emp.setRAZONEMPREV(rs.getString("RAZONEMPRE"));
                emp.setCODTIPOACTI(rs.getString("CODTIPOACTI"));
                emp.setNUMIPSS(rs.getString("NUMIPSS"));
                emp.setRNCEMPRE(rs.getString("RNCEMPRE"));
                emp.setFONOEMPRE(rs.getString("FONOEMPRE"));
                emp.setDIREEMPRE(rs.getString("DIREEMPRE"));
                emp.setACTIVEMPRE(rs.getBoolean("ACTIVEMPRE"));
                empresa.add(emp);
            }
            con.desconectar();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Message Select: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
            System.out.print("Vendor error code: ");
            System.out.println(ex.getErrorCode());
        }
        finally{
            con.desconectar();  
        }
        return empresa;
    }
}
```

En el formulario cargo de la siguiente manera mi pregunta es como puedo crear un modelo personalizado de una tabla para colocar un check en la tabla para el campo estado.

```
List EmpresaB;
```

DefaultTableModel tmEmpresa = new DefaultTableModel(null, new String[]
    {"CODIGO","RAZON","TIPO ACTIVIDAD","NUM IPS","RNC","TELEFONO","DIRECCION", "ESTADO"});

protected void listarEmpresa(){
        ControlEmpresa tActiv = new ControlEmpresa();
        EmpresaB = tActiv.listarEmpresa();
        mostrarEmpresa(EmpresaB);
    }
protected void mostrarEmpresa(List empresa){
        while(tmEmpresa.getRowCount()>0){
            tmEmpresa.removeRow(0);
        }
        if(empresa.isEmpty()){

`}
    else{
        String [] campos = new String[]{null,null,null,null};
        for(int i=0; i < empresa.size(); i++){
            tmEmpresa.addRow(campos);
            tmEmpresa.setValueAt(empresa.get(i).getNUMDOCUEMPRE(), i, 0);
            tmEmpresa.setValueAt(empresa.get(i).getRAZONEMPREV(), i, 1);
            tmEmpresa.setValueAt(empresa.get(i).getCODTIPOACTI(), i, 2);
            tmEmpresa.setValueAt(empresa.get(i).getNUMIPSS(), i, 3);
            tmEmpresa.setValueAt(empresa.get(i).getRNCEMPRE(), i, 4);
            tmEmpresa.setValueAt(empresa.get(i).getFONOEMPRE(), i, 5);
            tmEmpresa.setValueAt(empresa.get(i).getDIREEMPRE(), i, 6);
            tmEmpresa.setValueAt(empresa.get(i).getACTIVEMPRE(), i, 7);
        }
    }
}`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres que aparezca un checkbox en la columna estado redefine el modelo, así:

```
public class MiModelo extends javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel {

    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int columna) {
        if (columna == 8) {
            return (Boolean.class);
        }
        return super.getColumnClass(columna);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El siguiente fragmento de código manda a llamar la clase donde tienes la conexión con la base de datos. Como los datos lo guardas en una lista, usaríamos el ciclo **for** para iterar hasta que ya no hayan más filas, y manualmente indicas los datos, y así puedes capturar el valor booleano de la última columna y dependiendo si es `true` o `false` agregará una `x` o un `✓`.

```java
ControlEmpresa dao = new ControlEmpresa();
String datos[] = new String[8];
List<EmpresaBeans> empresaBeans= dao.select();

for (EmpresaBeans listaEmpresa : empresaBeans) {
    datos[0]=empresaBeans.getNUMDOCUEMPRE();
    datos[1]=empresaBeans.getRAZONEMPREV();
    datos[2]=empresaBeans.getCODTIPOACTI();
    datos[3]=empresaBeans.getNUMIPSS();
    datos[4]=empresaBeans.getRNCEMPRE();
    datos[5]=empresaBeans.getFONOEMPRE();
    datos[6]=empresaBeans.getDIREEMPRE();

    if (empresaBeans.getACTIVEMPRE() == true) {
        datos[7] = "✓";
    } else {
        datos[7] = "x";
    }
    
    tmEmpresa.addRow(datos);
}
```

Si no te convence esta forma, basándome como tienes en tu código, intentaría hacer algo como:

```java
if (empresa.get(i).getACTIVEMPRE() == true) {
    tmEmpresa.setValueAt("✓", i, 7);
} else {
    tmEmpresa.setValueAt("x", i, 7);
}
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(null, new String[]{"CODIGO", "RAZON", "TIPO ACTIVIDAD", "NUM IPS", "RNC", "TELEFONO", "DIRECCION", "ESTADO"});

        for (int i = 0; i < empresa.size(); i++) {
            model.addRow(new Object[]{empresa.get(i).getNUMDOCUEMPRE(), empresa.get(i).getRAZONEMPREV(), empresa.get(i).getCODTIPOACTI()});
        }

        table.setModel(model);
```

a tu tabla en este caso se llama table le modificas el modelo

Answer (score 0):

En tu caso, lo que yo haría es implementar un AbstractTableModel:

El código a continuación es un ejemplo de `AbstractTableModel` implementado, la explicación de los métodos sobre escritos la encuentras [en la API doc de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html).

```
public class EmpresaTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private static final String[] TITULOS = {
            "CODIGO",
            "RAZON",
            "TIPO ACTIVIDAD",
            "NUM IPS",
            "RNC",
            "TELEFONO",
            "DIRECCION",
            "ESTADO"
    };
    private static final Class<?>[] CLASES = {
            String.class,
            String.class,
            String.class,
            String.class,
            String.class,
            String.class,
            String.class,
            Boolean.class
    };

    private final List<EmpresaBeans> data = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return TITULOS.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return TITULOS[column];
    }

    @Override
    public int findColumn(String columnName) {
        for (var i = 0; i < TITULOS.length; i++) {
            if (columnName.equalsIgnoreCase(TITULOS[i])) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return CLASES[columnIndex];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0 -> getRow(rowIndex).getNUMDOCUEMPRE();
            case 1 -> getRow(rowIndex).getRAZONEMPREV();
            case 2 -> getRow(rowIndex).getCODTIPOACTI();
            case 3 -> getRow(rowIndex).getNUMIPSS();
            case 4 -> getRow(rowIndex).getRNCEMPRE();
            case 5 -> getRow(rowIndex).getFONOEMPRE();
            case 6 -> getRow(rowIndex).getDIREEMPRE();
            case 7 -> getRow(rowIndex).getACTIVEMPRE();
            default -> throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(columnIndex);
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0 -> getRow(rowIndex).setNUMDOCUEMPRE(aValue instanceof String val ? val : null);
            case 1 -> getRow(rowIndex).setRAZONEMPREV(aValue instanceof String val ? val : null);
            case 2 -> getRow(rowIndex).setCODTIPOACTI(aValue instanceof String val ? val : null);
            case 3 -> getRow(rowIndex).setNUMIPSS(aValue instanceof String val ? val : null);
            case 4 -> getRow(rowIndex).setRNCEMPRE(aValue instanceof String val ? val : null);
            case 5 -> getRow(rowIndex).setFONOEMPRE(aValue instanceof String val ? val : null);
            case 6 -> getRow(rowIndex).setDIREEMPRE(aValue instanceof String val ? val : null);
            case 7 -> getRow(rowIndex).setACTIVEMPRE(aValue instanceof Boolean val ? val : false);
            default -> throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(columnIndex);
        }
    }

    public EmpresaBeans getRow(int rowIndex) {
        return data.get(rowIndex);
    }
    
    //Agrega los métodos públicos que necesites
    //para manipular el listado (add, delete, indexOf, etc).
    
    public void addRow(EmpresaBeans empresa){
        data.add(empresa);
    }
    
    public void deleteRow(EmpresaBeans empresa){
        data.remove(empresa);
    }
}
```

Y uso eso en lugar del DefaultTableModel.

Comment: NOTA: mi respuesta utiliza características de java16, pero haciendo las modificaciones a la sintaxis apropiada, igual funciona en versiones anteriores.

Comment: Código sin explicación no es respuesta.

Comment: mi respuesta es breve: implementa un abstract table model. El código es un ejemplo de abstract table model implementado, la explicación de los métodos sobre escritos la encuentras en la API doc de Java https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html, no sé qué más expicación se le puede dar.

Answer (score -1):

Aquí te pongo un ejemplo de un código en el cual lleno un JTABLE con una serie de proyectos tomado de una base de datos. La parte que imagino que te interese del código viene después de crear el objeto `datos` de tipo `TableModel`.  `proy_table` es el nombre que le puse a mi JTABLE:

```
 private void aa() {
    proyectos = AccesoBD.Proyectos();
    final String[] columnas = {"ID", "Responsable", "Ejecutor", "Tiempo de Ejecución Estimado", "Costo Estimado", "Partes Interesadas"};
    TableModel datos = new DefaultTableModel(columnas, proyectos.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < proyectos.size(); i++) {
        Proy proyecto = proyectos.get(i);
        datos.setValueAt(proyecto.getId(), i, 0);
        datos.setValueAt(proyecto.getResponsable(), i, 1);
        datos.setValueAt(proyecto.getExecutor(), i, 2);
        datos.setValueAt(proyecto.getTiempo_exec_est(), i, 3);
        datos.setValueAt(proyecto.getEst_cost(), i, 4);
        datos.setValueAt(proyecto.getInterested_parts(), i, 5);
    }

    proy_table.setModel(datos);

}
```