# Programe un Jtable para que me muestre datos de una base de datos, me muestra la tabla pero no me muestra los datos

Tags: java, java-swing, jtable

Programe un jtable para que me muestre los usuarios de un programa de nomina, cuando lo programe en un solo ambiente funciona.
Al separarlo en capas como MVC no funciona, me muestra la tabla pero no me muestra los datos que tengo en la base de datos.
Tengo la conexion a la base de datos, y el enlace para que se comunique la vista con el controlador, me muestra la tabla, pero no me muestra los datos.

```
if (e.getSource().equals(Administrador.jButton_GestionarUsuarios)) {
        
            try {
           
            Connection cn = Conexion.conectar();
            PreparedStatement  pst = cn.prepareStatement(
                    "select id_usuario, nombre_usuario, username, tipo_nivel, estatus from usuarios");

            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
                     
            GestionarUsuarios.jTable_Usuarios = new JTable(model);
            GestionarUsuarios.jScrollPane_Usuarios.setViewportView(GestionarUsuarios.jTable_Usuarios);
                     
            model.addColumn(" ");
            model.addColumn("Nombre");
            model.addColumn("Username");
            model.addColumn("Permisos");
            model.addColumn("Estatus");
            
            while (rs.next()) {
                Object[] fila = new Object[5];

                for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                    fila[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);
                }
                model.addRow(fila);
            }
            
           /*GestionarUsuarios.jTable_Usuarios.setModel(model);*/
            
            cn.close();
                     
       }catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println("Error al llenar tabla." + ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al mostrar la informacion. ¡Contacte al Administrador!");

       }
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo crear un modelo de tabla para poder personalizar los componentes en un JTABLE?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59071/c%c3%b3mo-crear-un-modelo-de-tabla-para-poder-personalizar-los-componentes-en-un-jta)

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: El problema especifico es que no me muestra los datos que tengo en la base de datos, y no aparece ninguna mensaje de error al ejecutar el programa.